# Function with custom "class"

Tags: javascript

Basically I'd like a function that has an `instanceof Something === true`.

So something like `MySpecialKindOfFunction`, such that:

```js
if (theFunction instanceof MySpecialKindOfFunction)
```

I've tried setting the **proto** and constructor of the function without working.

Comment: Subclassing natives is problematic. Take look at [this article](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch28.html) or others out there. It might be possible with ECMA6, but I haven't looked into that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i don't understand your question but is this kind of thing you want to achieve?

```
// Static class method.
Interface.ensureImplements = function(object) {
    if(arguments.length < 2) {
        throw new Error("Function Interface.ensureImplements called with " +
        arguments.length + " arguments, but expected at least 2.");
    }
    for(var i = 1, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        var interface = arguments[i];
        if(interface.constructor !== Interface) {
            throw new Error("Function Interface.ensureImplements expects arguments"
            + " two and above to be instances of Interface.");
        }
        for(var j = 0, methodsLen = interface.methods.length; j < methodsLen; j++) {
            var method = interface.methods[j];
            if(!object[method] || typeof object[method] !== 'function') {
                throw new Error("Function Interface.ensureImplements: object "
                + "does not implement the " + interface.name
                + " interface. Method " + method + " was not found.");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I use this code to test if a function is a type of  Interface. The key code is :

```
if(interface.constructor !== Interface) {
```

To extends for a class you can do this :

```
function Item () {

};

function Picture () {
    Item.call(this); // Call to superClass constructor with subclass instance
};


Picture.prototype = new Item();
Picture.prototype.constructor = Picture;

var picture = new Picture();
if(picture instanceof Item){ 
    alert("True");
} else {
    alert(false);
}
```

Comment: I want a function that is instanceof SomethingElse. In other words, to subclass Function instead of Object.

Comment: I update my answer. In this example, Picture is a subclass of Item. The function extend can be where you want.

Comment: I need the class to be a function. That's what I mean by it needs to subclass Function. In other words, some var myVar, that can be called: myVar(), and that also is instanceof some "subclass" of Function.

Comment: Imagine something like this: class MyFunction extends Function; myFunc = new MyFunction(() => console.log("hello"); myFunc() // this logs hello. myFunc instanceof Function (returns true). myFunc instancsof MyFunciton //also returns true